# Selenium (.net) Send Text not being honored

Tags: c#, selenium

I have two text boxes that when I do a clear on the text they are recognized as being Cleared.  When I do a send keys although the element has the text the program does not recognize the text as being there.

I have tried the following options:

- Clicking elsewhere
  forcing the change using a `java` script (I program in .net)
  setting the text using send keys and forcing using `java` script
  Clicking pre and post.
- Manually moving on after the text has been sent does not work
  Manually clicking certain elements and then moving on does work. HTML

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. Please show what you've tried so far (code) and where you are having a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many methods of the javascript but here is what I have
SetText is an extension method I created which does a Clear and send keys
WaitSeconds is an extension method that does a thread. sleep
ClickJS is an extension method to just do a Javascript executor Click

```
 public PaneNewAdjustParameters SetBinningOptionMinSize(string minSize )
    {
        if (minSize == null) return this;

        txtMinimumSize.ClickJs(driver);
        driver.WaitSeconds(.5);
        txtMinimumSize.SetText(minSize);
        driver.WaitSeconds(.5);
        var drpdnMethod = driver.FindElement(By.Id("BinType"));
        drpdnMethod.ClickJs(driver);
        driver.WaitSeconds(2);
        return this;

        //JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
        //js.executeScript($"arguments{txtMinimumSize}.value={minSize};");


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry new to this posting code here is more complete HTML

```
<table style="width:100%;">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td class="inputlabel">
                <label for="BinType">Method</label>
            </td>
            <td class="inputcontrol">

                <select class="dropdown" data-bind="value: BinType" disabled="disabled" id="BinType" name="BinType"><option value="3">Moving</option>
```

Minimum Size
                
                
                    
                    
                    
                
            
            
                
                    Calculated Size
                
                
                    
                    
                    
                
            
            
                
                    Exclude Small Bins